# How can I convert a csv with 3 columns to a dictionary with 1 column as key, 1 column as its value and fetch the value for key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing a program to read and store the given email id and store its corresponding First Name in a data structure.

I tried running a for-loop after getting the email ids and searching for its corresponding First Name but it didn't work

This is what I have tried so far:

```
obj=function_which_reads_email

for i in obj:
   with open('..\Project2\newcsv.csv') as file:
           data = csv.reader(file)

   df.loc=[df['Email']==i,'First_name']
```

Always receiving the same error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at line ...

Comment: pd.read_json('..\Project2\newcsv.csv') ?

Comment: Your open statement as a mistake you are missing a `'`, it should be ```with open('..\Project2\newcsv.csv') as file:```

Comment: Can you please be more specific? are you reading into pandas df? did you mean df.loc[df['Email']==i,'firstName']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but I got the solution. I stored the file path in a .json file and I read the file path, opened it and then returned the first name of the corresponding email id in a dictionary.

d={}                                                                    #creating dictionary

```
with open('signature.json') as sig:
    user = json.load(sig)                                               #load signature block of sender from json file into 'user'


path = user['File_path']                                                #storing path of input file in 'path'



with open(path,'r', newline='') as f:                                   #opening input csv file
    reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=',')
    next(reader)

    for user_data in reader:                                            #iterating through file
        d[user_data[4]]=user_data[0]                                    #assigning name as value and  email id as key

return d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

#First read csv pd.read_csv()
df = pd.DataFrame([['a',2],['b',4]],columns=['col1','col2'])

#value : col1 and key = col2
dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(df)):
    dictionary[df.iloc[i][0]] = df.iloc[i][1]
```